disk0s1 failed to mount for firmware update for WifFi & bluetooth while dual booting MacOS Sonoma and Fedora, following steps of T2Linux
After Installing T2Linux Fedora (https://wiki.t2linux.org/), I did the following:
me@mes-MacBook-Pro ~ % bash ~/Downloads/firmware.sh
Detected macOS
Mounting the EFI partition
Password:
Volume ondisk0s1 failed to mount because it appears to be
an APFS Physical Store (or is the APFS Container already mounted?)
See "diskutil apfs list"

me@mes-MacBook-Pro ~ % diskutil apfs list
APFS Container (1 found)

+-- Container disk1 1A213F99-4048-4B29-AD6D-195EBD53AF28
APFS Container Reference: disk1
Size (Capacity Ceiling): 400240963584 B (400.2 GB)
Capacity In Use By Volumes: 30537031680 B (30.5 GB) (7.6% used)
Capacity Not Allocated: 369703931904 B (369.7 GB) (92.4% free)

+-< Physical Store disk0s1 0F43F088-608E-4665-97AC-EF1A7979F57C
APFS Physical Store Disk: disk0s1
Size: 400240963584 B (400.2 GB)

+-> Volume disk1s1 A5905225-8E1C-4917-B201-746EA372CF44
APFS Volume Disk (Role): disk1s1 (System)
Name: Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
Mount Point: Not Mounted
Capacity Consumed: 10238320640 B (10.2 GB)
Sealed: Yes
FileVault: No (Encrypted at rest)
Snapshot: 8856CF34-ACC5-49D3-B513-427607B599D1
Snapshot Disk: disk1s1s1
Snapshot Mount Point: /
Snapshot Sealed: Yes

+-> Volume disk1s2 C6538623-D168-488A-97CD-7DAEB17D36FC
APFS Volume Disk (Role): disk1s2 (Preboot)
Name: Preboot (Case-insensitive)
Mount Point: /System/Volumes/Preboot
Capacity Consumed: 4024815616 B (4.0 GB)
Sealed: No
FileVault: No

+-> Volume disk1s3 7C253EB3-5A75-4676-99DA-790FFC90DDD4
APFS Volume Disk (Role): disk1s3 (Recovery)
Name: Recovery (Case-insensitive)
Mount Point:Not Mounted
Capacity Consumed: 2399240192 B (2.4 GB)
Sealed: No
FileVault: No

+-> Volume disk1s4 3B521A91-8933-4174-AB45-D4A30124CD3E
APFS Volume Disk (Role): disk1s4 (Data)
Name: Macintosh HD - Data (Case-insensitive)
Mount Point: /System/Volumes/Data
Capacity Consumed: 13717004288 B (13.7 GB)
Sealed: No
FileVault: No (Encrypted at rest)

+-> Volume disk1s6 4811901A-F2E0-4079-B220-8B425CB90C26
APFS Volume Disk (Role): disk1s6 (VM)
Name: VM (Case-insensitive)
Mount Point: /System/Volumes/VM
Capacity Consumed: 20480 B (20.5 KB)
Sealed: No
FileVault: No

Had everything gone well, the Ideal installation output should have been:
me@mes-MacBook-Pro ~ % bash ~/Downloads/firmware.sh
Detected macOS
Mounting the EFI partition
Password:
Volume EFI on disk0s1 mounted
Getting Wi-Fi and Bluetooth firmware
Copying this script to EFI
Unmounting the EFI partition
Volume EFI on disk0s1 unmounted

Any help?
